# Aurelia with jquery datatables usage error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, aurelia, jspm

I'm having trouble using jquery datatables with Aurelia. 
I'm trying to import datatables, but with no luck. When I try to initialize it, it gives me error

> Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function(…)

My typescript code is following:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as dataTable from 'datatables';
export class App {
router: Router;

constructor() {}
attached() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "paginate": true,
        "pageLength": 25
    });
} 
 activate() {  
    console.log("app.activate");
}....
```

Any pointers? 
Cheers :)

Comment: i don't know what datatables is, but i would try using `import $ from 'jquery'` or `import 'jquery'` and also `import 'datatables'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here that will be causing headaches for you.

Firstly, jQuery exports a default variable of $. So you can do the following to import jQuery inside of a ViewModel:

```
import 'jquery';
```

Secondly, the DataTables plugin extends jQuery's library prototype to add itself to the jQuery object. So to get this to work you need to include jQuery first and then the DataTables plugin afterwards.

I couldn't see a default export for client-side usage, so this should give you the following and hopefully functional code:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'datatables';
```

Unless I overlooked a particular detail, I believe this should solve the problem. If not, then drop a comment below and we will get it sorted either way.

Comment: Hi , tried different ways, and found that I got it working when I just called imported dataTable as a function in activate() method<br>
>activate(){
> dataTable(); ...
>}
Importing the way you suggested got me jquery 'undefined' when I tried to console.log it.

Comment: How and where are you console logging the "$" export from jQuery? Because if you do it from outside of the app, I believe it won't work as everything inside of the modules system is encapsulated from the global namespace. If you were to console.log($); from within attached() you should definitely see it displaying something.

Comment: Hey, when I try to import it your way, then I get an error 
"src\app.ts(6,8): error TS1192: Module '"jquery"' has no default export."
So I need to Import it 
import * as $ from 'jquery';

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried just using ``import 'jquery'`` at the top of your ViewModel as well? I believe that should work as jQuery will setup globals from within itself.

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] I got it working by initializing datatable in the activate() method and leaving my imports the way they are...

```
activate() {  
   datatable();
   console.log("app.activate");
}....
```

Tried a little further, found that this also works...

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import "datatables";
//import * as dataTable from "datatable";

export class DatatablesExample {    
   //activate() {
   //    dataTable();
   //}
    attached() {
        $('#example').dataTable();
    }
}
```

Quess my problem all along was importing jQuery.
But I wonder why the recommended import doesn't work for jquery...

> import $ from 'jquery';

Comment: This code worked for me. `import $ from 'jquery';
import dataTable from 'datatables';`